# How to write score to SQLite db?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

i'm a sqlite newbie. What I'm trying to do...I have a game and after the game ends it stores time result in a double variable named elapsedSeconds. I want to place that result in a db, and than in my dedicated activity show top 10 scores for the user. I have HighScoreDb class where I create a db (i used some code I found online, but I think it'll serve my purpose). Here's the code.

```
public class HighScoreDb {
    private static class HighScoreDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public HighScoreDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
        db.execSQL(SCORE_TABLE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.i("Error", "Error making database");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SCORE_TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    }

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String SCORE_TABLE_NAME = "highscore";
    private static final String SCORE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
                             + SCORE_TABLE_NAME
                             + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, "
                             + "name TEXT NOT NULL, score DOUBLE  NOT NULL)";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "highscores.db";
    // The index (key) column name for use in where clauses.
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

    // The name and column index of each column in your database.
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    public static final int NUMBER_COLUMN = 2;
    public static final int SCORE_COLUMN = 3;

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context ctx;
    private final HighScoreDbHelper dbHelper;

    public HighScoreDb(Context context) {
    this.ctx = context;
    ctx.deleteDatabase(SCORE_TABLE_NAME);
    dbHelper = new HighScoreDbHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
    }

    }

    public void createRow(String name, int score) {
    ContentValues intialValue = new ContentValues();
    intialValue.put("name", name);
    intialValue.put("score", score);
    db.insertOrThrow(SCORE_TABLE_NAME, null, intialValue);

    }

    public void deleteRow(long rowId) {
    db.delete(SCORE_TABLE_NAME, "_id=" + rowId, null);
    }

    public Cursor GetAllRows() {
    try {
        return db.query(SCORE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "_id", "name", "score" }, null,
                null, null, null, "score DESC");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.i("Error on query", e.toString());
        return null;
    }

    }

    public void updateRow(long _id, String name, String score) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put("name", name);
    args.put("number", score);
    db.update(SCORE_TABLE_NAME, args, "_id=" + _id, null);
    }

}
```

From this table I will not need column name, cause I will just have 10 places with scores. How to insert that result in this db after my game ends? I think I know how to read from it, i will do something like this:

```
HighScoreDb db = new HighScoreDb(this);
Cursor myCursor = db.GetAllRows();
myCursor.moveToPosition(0);
    String Row1Value2 = myCursor.getString(2);
myCursor.close();
db.close();
```

I'm calling it in my games class like this:

```
HighScoreDb db = new HighScoreDb(this);
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `createRow(String name, int score)`? If so, why doesn't it work? One thing I noticed is that you open your db in the constructor and keep it open until `close()` is called. You should better only open the database before you want to read or write a record

Comment: Everything i've tried is right there in the code. :) Can we start slow? I have two variables set after game end, insertName which is a String and elapsedSeconds which is an Int. How to insert these value into my database?

Comment: well then you can just call `createRow(insertName, elapsedSeconds)` and it should work. however, you have to change your statement `SCORE_TABLE_CREATE` to create a column of type `INTEGER` instead of `DOUBLE`. Or you have to change the `createRow` parameters to `String, double`, or `String, float` because I don't know if SQLite can handle double. I would recommend staying with integers however and changing your measurements to milliseconds. That is the de-facto norm for time measurements.

Comment: OK, i'll change it int. One more thing, where is the best place to call createRow? Can I do it right after my game ends, in my game activity?

Comment: yes, the call doesn't cause any delays, you can safely call it in your UI thread as soon as you want to save the value

Comment: I get error when using db.createRow(insertNameString, elapsedSeconds); No record in logcat. I use it after I insert my name in alert dialog editbox. Convert editable to string (to insertNameString).

Comment: There has to be an error in the output. Please check under "All Messages". Btw. why do you call `ctx.deleteDatabase(SCORE_TABLE_NAME);` in your constructor? This won't work, because it would require `DATABASE_NAME ` if you really want to do that. But I can't think of a reason why you would want to delete your database every time you start your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i've understand your question... To put some datas in your db, you just have to correctly use your functions wrote below (i assume your class is working fine), for example :

```
HighScoreDbHelper myDbHelper = new HighScoreDbHelper(yourContext);
myDbHelper.createRow(yourName, yourScore);
```

This tutorial is a good starter to sqlite concepts : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The way you open the database is fine.

Instead of using a cursor to get the particular information about a row, make an entity that represents a row inside the table. Create a list of these objects using the information from the Cursor.

```
public UserScore {
    String name;
    Integer score; // don't know why you would use double here.

    // getters + setters or make it immutable
}
```

What I would provide is some method inside HighScoreDb to add a new score. For example with signature

```
public void addScore(UserScore userScore);
```

Don't think about just adding 10 scores, add every score to the database. Whenever you want the top 10 scores. Just query the last 10 scores descending. Otherwise you are programming a lot of complexity which is easily done with a query. To do this look into top-N queries.

An example writing to the DB inside the helper is like this, (didn't test the SQL but it should be in this form)

```
this.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("insert into highscore (name, score) values (" + userScore.getName() + "," + userScore.getScore() + ")");
```

Comment: I use double because my results are something like 34,54 seconds, or 12,68 seconds.

Comment: Maybe look into BigDecimal if you want to use 2 decimals.

Comment: That is my smallest concern. I need to figure it out how to write my results to in and then how to read from it. Like I said, SQLite is not my stronger suit.